# Floating point exception (core dumped) - c program

Tags: c

I have a question on one of my assignements:

1. Write a program that allows the user to type in simple expressions of the form
   number operator number
2. The program evaluates the expression and displays the results at the terminal, to two decimal places of accuracy.
3. The program, however, is allowed to call the scanf function only once.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, sum, difference, product, quotient;

    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;

    printf("type in expression");
    scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);

    sum = num1+num2;
    difference = num1-num2;
    product = num1*num2;
    quotient = num1/num2;


    switch (num1) {
        case 2: printf("%d/%d=%d", num1, num2!=0 , quotient);
                    break;
        case 1: printf("%d*%d=%d", num1, num2, product);
                    break;
        case 0: printf("%d-%d=%d", num1, num2, difference);
                    break;
        default: printf("%d+%d=%d", num1, num2, sum);
                    break;
    }       
}
```

The program can be compiled, but when I run it, this message shows up:

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

What does this mean? Also, if there is anything else wrong with it, please let me know.

Comment: What is the input ? What is the expected output for that input ?

Comment: It means most likely that  `num2` is 0 and division by 0 is a problem.

Comment: Why prints are in switch()?  Though it is nothing to do with the exception.

Comment: BTW: how can you get a "Floating point exception" here. I don't see any `float` or `double` in your proram. Are you sure the program you are running is the program you posted here ?

Comment: The output is supposed to be either the sum, difference, produtct or quotient depending on what operation you used.

Comment: To add to what @MichaelWalz said, I couldn't reproduce the issue [here](http://ideone.com/wOmS3v).

Comment: I can reproduce for using 2 as `num1` and 0 as `num2`, this is simply a division by zero.

Comment: How would i fix the problem of dividing by 0?

Comment: You are not reading the operator from user.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I also get a floating point exception here. My guess is it is casted to float for the division and is then truncated down.

Comment: @MayurK: He is, look at the switch. The operand is based on what you enter for `num1`, e.g. entering 2 will result in division.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Read the code. He is just using `scanf` to get two numbers. Both are operands and `num1` is also the operator type

Comment: @Nidhoegger He is using num2 for that. But he is suppose to read operator character is think.

Comment: @Nidhoegger yes I know, see my previous comments. But I don't understand how you can get a floating point exception, `quotient = num1/num2;` deals exclusively with `int`s so there should be no cast (or rather promotion) here. What compiler do you use ?

Comment: @MayurK: That was not the question nor do we have any informations on that. His problem is the line where he divides and does not check for zero. That answers his question.

Comment: When i run the program, adding and subtracting the two variables num1 and num2 doesn't give me any problems, but when i divide or multiply, that error message shows up.

Comment: I used the gcc compiler

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed you got the answer in the comments multiple times...

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed you are dividing by zero, because the way you read your expression it wrong.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed and please look at the first comment and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Integer division by 0 is often reported as a "Floating point exception".  The message mis-leads.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int num1=0, num2=0;
        char operation= ' ';

        printf("type in expression\n");
        scanf("%d %c %d", &num1, &operation, &num2);

        switch (operation) {
            case '/': {
                        if(0 == num2) //This is the solution for your issue.
                        {
                            printf("\nCan not perform %d/%d", num1, num2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("\n%d / %d=%d", num1, num2, num1/num2);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case '*': printf("\n%d * %d=%d", num1, num2, num1*num2);
                        break;
            case '-': printf("\n%d - %d=%d", num1, num2, num1-num2);
                        break;
            case '+': printf("\n%d + %d=%d", num1, num2, num1+num2);
                        break;
            default: printf("\nInvalid operation[%c]", operation);
                        break;
        } 
        return 0;      
    }
```

Comment: Sorry. But I just answered his question.

Comment: [Read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @MichaelWalz. Understood. I didn't know about this. I will be careful in future.